# Sitecore presentation layout details - control with unique name when added more than once

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

[Items Presentation one control with multiple occurence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snIBH.png)

When same control is added more than once for an item's presentation, is there a way to change/set unique control name that shows up on layout details window, rather having same name for all.

Comment: Are using Dynamic Placerholders? http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/dynamic-placeholders/

Comment: No we are not using dynamic placeholders.We need to use the same control with different data source within the same placeholder and we need to differentiate with unique control name when it shows on layout details window as a part of presentation details.